# Yup and Typescript Schema Interface for `Yup.lazy()`

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, yup

im struggling to create a typescript interface for a yup schema (https://github.com/jquense/yup/blob/master/docs/typescript.md)

given the typescript interface:

```js
interface TestInterface {
  name: string;
};
```

the following return type is valid:

```js
const testSchema: Yup.SchemaOf<TestInterface> = Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup.string().required()
});
```

but in my code i have `Yup.lazy()` being used, but im unable to find out how i should create an interface for the following:

```js
const testSchema: Yup.SchemaOf<TestInterface> = Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup.lazy(() => Yup.string().required())
});
```

the error i get is:

```
Type 'ObjectSchema<Assign<ObjectShape, { name: Lazy<RequiredStringSchema<string, Record<string, any>>, Record<string, any>>; }>, Record<...>, TypeOfShape<...>, AssertsShape<...>>' is not assignable to type 'ObjectSchemaOf<TestInterface>'.
  Type 'Assign<ObjectShape, { name: Lazy<RequiredStringSchema<string, Record<string, any>>, Record<string, any>>; }>' is not assignable to type '{ name: BaseSchema<string, AnyObject, string>; }'.
    Types of property 'name' are incompatible.
      Type 'Lazy<RequiredStringSchema<string, Record<string, any>>, Record<string, any>>' is missing the following properties from type 'BaseSchema<string, AnyObject, string>': deps, tests, transforms, conditions, and 35 more.ts(2322)
```

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: Unfortunately no; but I'm still keen to get an answer on this.

Answer (score 1):

Your example works as you'd like using `Yup.ObjectSchema` with the addition of requiring your object.

Be sure to add `.required()` onto your `.shape` or `.object` chain so that the fields of your schema are certain to exist from TypeScript's perspective. It is in essence acting as `NonNullable<TestInterface>`

```js
//    ✅ happy type
const testSchema1: Yup.ObjectSchema<TestInterface> = Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup.string().required(),
}).required();

//    ✅ happy type
const testSchema2: Yup.ObjectSchema<TestInterface> = Yup.object().shape({
  name: Yup.lazy(() => Yup.string().required())
}).required();
```

***Note***: Working with the current (as of this post) version 0.32.11. A runkit example in plain JS with stubbed out types can be seen [[here](https://runkit.com/joematune/6229b28235b59d00099e0476)]

***Source***: https://github.com/jquense/yup/#ensuring-a-schema-matches-an-existing-type